# Connecting two PCs with laplink cable without additional SW on one of them

Tags: command-line, file-transfer, data-transfer, com, windows-95

I have an old laptop running Windows 95, a quite clean installation. Its floppy drive recently died and since it has no CD drive, ethernet or USB, I am almost out of options how to get data into it.

The computer does have a COM port (male). Is it possible to transfer data to the Windows 95 machine via COM port using a Laplink cable, without having to install additional software to the old computer? (installing new software is not possible, because, again, I wouldn't have any way how to get the installer onto the machine)

As for the PC that would send the data, I could use a computer running 95, 98, 2000 or XP, all with a male COM port (and could install new software on it).

My goal is to be able to get data to-and-from the machine without having to disassemble it.

Comment: Whats the end goal? Are you trying to continue to use this machine, or are you just wanting the data off of it? Easiest way for the latter is to remove the hard drive and plug the hard drive in to a newer machine, or use an IDE to USB adapter.

Comment: I edited the question (I want to continue to use the machine without having to disassemble it).

Comment: Is [direct cable connection](http://www.trine2.net.au/PC%20to%20PC%20Connect/directcc95.htm) installed on the Win95 machine?

Comment: Alternatively you can also use HyperTerminal.

Comment: You may want to have a look at this - - https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000246.htm

Comment: I just tried to transfer a file between two virtual machines with hyperterminal since that is included with Win95 and very easy to use. Here is a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/4hvYJ) of my attempt. It works very well. When it asks you to select a modem click `cancel` and then make a new connection and select direct connection on com1. Also pick a reasonable speed. Every com port should support at least 115kb/s.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, guys. I think I'll try the hyperterminal approach SpiderPig mentioned, it sounds like the thing I'm looking for